# Groovy Mixin use method of mixed class

Tags: groovy, mixins

Consider a mixin class

```
class StringPlusMixin {
  String plus(String other) {
    return toString() + other
  }
}
```

And his use case

```
@Mixin(StringPlusMixin)
class POGO {
  String descr
  String toString(){
    return descr
  }
}
```

Is there some way to make `SringPlusMixin` to use `POGO#toString()` instead of `SringPlusMixin#toString()` ?

The actual output is:

```
POGO pogo = new POGO(descr: "POGO description");
System.out.println(pogo + "Some message."); //StringPlusMixin@f410f8 Some message.
```

I'm considering to use this mixin since the Groovy default of `instance + String` is to try to call a `plus()` method. I'm using my `POGO` in several Java classes and trying to not need to change all messages to use `toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [@Delegate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Delegate+transformation) transformation in POGO.

```
@Mixin(StringPlusMixin)
class POGO {
  @Delegate String descr
  String toString(){
    return descr
  }
}
```

Since `descr` is owned by POGO, in runtime use of `descr` is delgated to the owner which is POGO.

Comment: I tested this and works perfect! To me it makes sense if the `StringPlusMixin` used directly `descr`. Still not clear to me why with the @Delegate in the attribute Groovy start calling `toString()` of POGO instead of `toString()` of `StringPlusMixin`. This still works if I change the method to: `String toString(){ return "[$descr]" }`, for example.

Comment: I understand, it works perfect here because @Delegate overrides everything (even the Mixins) and tries to invoke the default `toString()` of String class. But in this case, `toString` has been overriden by POGO, do it uses that at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection? Also, i turned your class into a Category, by making the method static and passing the child object as first parameter.

**Update**: as per comments, removed the type from the mixin method

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper as Invoker

class StringPlusMixin {
  static String plus(pogo, String other) {
    def toString = pogo.class.declaredMethods.find { it.name == "toString" }
    return toString.invoke(pogo) + other
  }
}


@Mixin(StringPlusMixin)
class POGO {
  String descr
  String toString(){
    return descr
  }
}


pogo = new POGO(descr: "POGO description")
assert pogo + " Some message." == "POGO description Some message."
```

Comment: Isn't this way the Mixin(StringPlusMixin) tightly coupled to POGO? If I have `POGO1` using this Mixin, how would I handle? Creating a Category interface with POGO and POGO1 implementing it?

Comment: The idea is to apply StringPlusMixin to any class, so creating a static method tightly coupled will not help me, but thanks for answering.

Comment: @SérgioMichels The category can be dynamic. Updated the code.

Comment: @WillP Any reason to your mixin implementation have the plus method as static? Looking [in the javadocs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GString.html) it seems to be only public, what I'm missing?

Comment: @SérgioMichels The Mixin class is treated as a Category. Have a look at this [sample](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-use-categories-to-add.html).

Comment: @dmahapatro aha! Now it makes sense :-)